# Is there a way to find the pod that was update after pod update in post_install

Tags: cocoapods, cocoapods-1.2

Trying to catch the pod that was updated using

pod update

I want to catch the pod and eventually find its target(I know how to find the target)
what I wanted is there a way to catch  or target that got update in post_install

Comment: pod update <podname> is the command

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal then,
**cd ios**
enter and type **arch -x86_64 pod update** then enter.
Now run application.
(On Mac m1 work for me)